# How to make menu-bar auto-hide/appear faster?

Tags: macos, mac, menu-bar, animation

There is a 0.5s delay and then the animation starts to roll the menu bar down. I know it doesn't sound a lot but in practice it gets annoying when I multitask and trying get tasks done fast.

Is there a way to remove the delay and trigger the animation instantaneously?
Also, is there way to make the animation faster, or perhaps disable it?

Answer (score 0):

If by menu-bar you mean the dock, you can disable it.

Under System Preferences you'll find a submenu for Dock settings

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that by the 'menu bar', the OP actually meant the 'menu bar'.  In El Capitan. Just a guess, but given Apple's historical possessiveness about the menu bar, I doubt there is an easy option. Happy to be wrong though...